# Why does afl-clang-fast compile bitcode with an error?

Tags: compilation, clang, llvm, fuzzing

I used the tool [gllvm](https://github.com/White-Mouse/gllvm) to build the whole-program LLVM bitcodes file (tiffsplit.bc). Then I used afl-clang-fast compile it to generate the instrumented binary. However, it gives an error. I found a similar problem on [github](https://github.com/evanmak/savior-source/issues/13).  I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

My commands are as follows:

```
CC=gclang  ./configure  --enable-shared=no --enable-static=yes
make -j$(nproc)
get-bc tiffsplit
afl-clang-fast tiffsplit.bc -o tiffsplit
```

The error is as follwos:
[image]

```
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `TIFFDefaultTransferFunction':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:143: undefined reference to `pow'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:143: undefined reference to `floor'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:143: undefined reference to `pow'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:143: undefined reference to `floor'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:143: undefined reference to `pow'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:143: undefined reference to `floor'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `DoubleToRational':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `floor'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `floor'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `floor'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `DoubleToSrational':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `floor'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o:/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: more undefined references to `floor' follow
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `LogL16toY':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `exp'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `LogL16fromY':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `log'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `log'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `XYZtoRGB24':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `LogL10toY':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `exp'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `LogL10fromY':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `log'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `oog_encode':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `atan2'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `atan2'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `LogLuv24toXYZ':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `exp'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `LogLuv24fromXYZ':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `log'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `LogLuv32toXYZ':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `exp'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `LogLuv32fromXYZ':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `log'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `log'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `Luv24toRGB':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `Luv32toXYZ':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `exp'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `Luv32toRGB':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `exp'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `L16toY':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `exp'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `L16toGry':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `exp'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `Luv24fromXYZ':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `log'
/tmp/tiffsplit-fcc4f4.o: In function `L16fromY':
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `log'
/home/ubuntu/tiff-4.3.0/libtiff/tif_aux.c:409: undefined reference to `log'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Try `afl-clang-fast tiffsplit.bc -o tiffsplit -lm`? The problem is a missing link against `libm` but I am not familiar with "afl-clang-fast" to know if it supports `-l` flag or if it will pass it along to the underlying link step.

Answer (score 1):

```
afl-clang-fast tiffsplit.bc -o tiffsplit -lm
```